# C# - How to register onMouseClick in real time?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, picturebox

I am writing a silly little program (as we all do from time to time) to work on some basic C# coding.  As I'm sure you can see, the mouse is clicked, the picture moves until it's at the place where the mouse was clicked.  This bit works fine.  I then want the picturebox to move randomly, which I have also managed!  The next problem I have is that when I click, instead of moving to the new mouse coordinates, the picturebox continues to move randomly.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!  Here is the code I think is the problem.

Many Thanks!

John

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseClick(e);
    int destX = e.X;
    int destY = e.Y;

        HasArrived = false;

    while (HasArrived == false)
    {
    moveImage(destX, destY, pictureBox1);

        if (pictureBox1.Left == destX && pictureBox1.Top == destY)
        {
            HasArrived = true;
            while (HasArrived == true)
            {
                randomMove(pictureBox1);
                hungry1 += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stucked in your inner loop!
Try to put the loop in a backgroundworker,
so you can recognize the new mouseclick to set HasArrived to true.

And using the negative while statement in the positive while statemant seems very bad to me,
ive never seen that before.
I dont think thiss will work fine..

Comment: As the control is created in a different thread, would I have to use an Invoke (or BeginInvoke in this case) to get access to the control?

Comment: yes or you could use progresschanged, but i dont know if it will freeze the gui?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because HasArrived never gets set to false anywhere? But that will also mean you will be stuck in your Move loop as well.

EDIT:  If you want to only move randomly once after you move to the position you clicked at, then remove the while around the random bit, else you'll need some other variable to know when to break out of the while.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop seems to have a problem.

```
        HasArrived = true;
        while (HasArrived == true)
        {
            randomMove(pictureBox1);
            hungry1 += 1;
        }
```

Unless randomMove() can modify HasArrived, your loop never set HasArrived to false, so the while condition is always true, and you will never get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like its because once the picture moves to its destination your program is stuck in a tight while loop from which it never escapes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate more your answer please

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never test equality of variables with boolean expressions. This means `HasArrived == false` is bad and it is better to write it like this:

```
while (!HasArrived)
{
    // ...
    while (HasArrived)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that your program does not give back control to the form, after the mouse has been clicked once.

Let me illustrate, what your program does as soon as the mouse has been clicked:

1. remember new x and y coords
2. while the picture has not arrived, move the image
3. in case the picture has arrived it's destination - move it around randomly

But it ends up moving the picture around until you kill the program, because your form does still handle the "OnMouseClicked"-event. And as long as the program does not return from your event handling method, the form is unable to record any other event (typically it should freeze, ending with "Application not responding").

So from what I think your code is supposed to do you should code your program like this:
1. Create a parallel thread to move around your image randomly
2. Pause the thread as long as your mouse-click event has not yet been handled

Also your question is wrong at all. Realtime means that your program is able to **give any result in a predefined time-limit**. Your method does not fit this at all, beacause the time your method takes for execution depends on how fast your image moves and which distance it should move.